# Solr is returning undesired results

Tags: solr

I have run one solr query with `q=titlekeywordAbstract:organic`. System is including the results with organisation/Organization also which doesn't contains organic. How I can solve this issue?

1.solr query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/articlecore/select/?q=(titleKeywordsAbs:organic) &stopwords=true&defType=edismax&rows=15&start=0&facet.mincount=1&q.op=AND&hl=true&hl.fragsize=200&hl.fl=title_fz,keywords_fz&hl.simple.post=</mark >&hl.simple.pre=<mark >&wt=json
```

2.field definition

```
<field indexed="true" name="titleKeywordsAbs" multiValued="true" stored="false" type="text_general_singular_plural"/>
```

3.field type

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_general_singular_plural" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" format="wordset"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" format="wordset"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you run the query in debug mode `debug=true`? This will help you understand how the query is parsed and I would bet the stemming filter you set are responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: Please add relevant documents that show what's being included that you believe shouldn't be included - be aware that stemming can sometimes make a stem / base form that you didn't think of between seemingly unrelated words (i.e. they are unrelated by meaning, not by stem). There is also no need for `()` around a single term as in your query. You can use the `Analysis` page under Solr admin to test the query against the indexed text for the field to see why a hit was generated (and `debug=all` as mentioned will tell you why a document was included by showing which fields that matched.

Comment: 1. This is the one of the sample document. This came only because of the presence of organizations in abstract.

Comment: Abstract : The experiences of fourteen students in the student occupations in the Brazilian state of Minas Gerais in 2016 are analyzed, through semi-structured interviews, addressing how much the educational dimension ofthis movement has affected their political trajectories. Despite the fact that there were few effective engagements in political organizations

Comment: 2.Result of debug  debug": {
"rawquerystring": "titleKeywordsAbs:organic",
"querystring": "titleKeywordsAbs:organic",
"parsedquery": "+(+titleKeywordsAbs:organ)",
"parsedquery_toString": "+(+titleKeywordsAbs:organ)",
"explain": {
"11246875": "\n2.686988 = weight(titleKeywordsAbs:organ in 428804) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  2.686988 = score(freq=6.0), product of:\n    2.8750582 = idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:\n      4115089 = n, number of documents containing term\n      72945949 = N,

Comment: My question is  how system is derived the below part "parsedquery": "+(+titleKeywordsAbs:organ)", Means instead of "Organic" parsing only for "organ"